# FTP Upload Hook

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, ubuntu-12.04

I need to be notified and perform other tasks when a file is uploaded onto my server. Is there any method/system call that will be triggered or anything that i can hook onto ? I'm using vsftpd as my ftp server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approach this by using something more generic than a FTP hook (which will also allow it to scale if the users uses SCP, SFTP or even SSH using a text editor): inotify.

There are many languages that support this, but here's a Python API: https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki

This would allow you to watch a directory, and when it changes, act on that information.

There is also Python Watchdog: http://code.google.com/p/python-watchdog

Comment: Thanks. Am looking into this. Any idea which event will be triggered at the end of a file transfer ?

Comment: FTP clients normally upload files in with a filename like ".something" and rename them when they're done, so you can just ignore hidden files if that's the case and just wait for the 'real' file to be created.